# Bad T-SQL code for account creation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I create a User using SQL code to join an SQL Server via SQL Server authentication mode. I used the code

```
CREATE LOGIN ANNACASSAR
  WITH PASSWORD = '';
GO

CREATE USER ANNACASSAR FOR LOGIN ANNACASSAR;
GO
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot connect to moscow\SQLSERVERMSWDEV.
>
> Additional information:
>   login failed for user ANNACASSAR
>
> (Microsoft SQL Server error 18456)

Comment: Cannot connect to moscow\SQLSERVERMSWDEV. additional information login failed for user ANNACASSAR. (MISCROSOFT SQL SERVER ERROR 18456)

Comment: i need to create that user to login on the SQLSERVERMSWDEV instance how would the complete code be please using the details i gave?

Comment: See [Basic SQL Server Security concepts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lcris/2007/03/23/basic-sql-server-security-concepts-logins-users-and-principals/) for more information

Comment: I didn't really understand what you meant sorry. The thing I need to do is create a User Called Anna Cassar and this user will be able to access SQLSERVERMSWDEV instance via sql authenctication mode.

Comment: I need Anna cassar to be able to login to the SQLSERVERMSWDEV database instance

Comment: Where is the link please sorry but it's a task i have for school which we had to search online and Im really not into SQL im studying networking.

Comment: Can you paste the total error message along with state

Answer (score 0):

Set your server to Mixed authentication mode (right-click on the server in SSMS, Properties, Security, SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode, then restart the server).

However, you really should set a password, because it's a real security risk to create a login without a password.